# best design for a class with specified objects

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, object

I have a class for example MySetting

```
public class MySetting
{
    public string Name {set; get;}
    public TileBeh Tile{set; get;}
}
```

objects of this class are specified. I meanو they are predefined. these objects are constant in all application. they also fix in whole of app's life time. how can manage these object which understanding of code is improved. Any suggestion?

Update:

for example, there are four objects of this class in whole of application.

1. None
2. Dynamic
3. Last
4. First

and If I can use them as following way is appropriate:

```
MySetting.None.Value
```

Comment: `Any suggestion?` - Yes. Please try to improve your question. I can't understand what you need and what your problem is.

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are asking, but i would guess you want to know about static classes. You need something per class not per instance, that gives you static.

Comment: What platform (e.g. Windows Forms, Web Forms) is this application running on?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: the platform is not important I want to find a design solution

Comment: @Mahdi, if I were you I would consider answering the question when people ask. The platform, when ensuring a class lasts the lifetime of the application, is quite important -or at least it was until you decided to actually put a little effort into the question. Remember, you're question was terribly written and we are helping you **for free** because **you** don't know what to do.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud : I appreciate for your help, I think the platform will be windows or mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a class structure like this:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static MySetting None = new MySetting() { ... };
    public static MySetting Dynamic = new MySetting() { ... };
}
```

You could even build a static constructor in that `Settings` class to initialize the static fields like this:

```
public static Settings() { ... }
```

Further, you could turn those into properties if you wanted, maybe like this:

```
public static MySetting None { get; private set; }
```

which would encapsulate the class even more. You have quite a few options surrounding how you want to encapsulate the `fields` or `properties`.

Comment: @Mahdi, not a problem, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: I know it wasn't good question, but there is no silly question. ;) thanks again

Comment: @Mahdi, I never implied it was a silly question, or even a bad question, I literally stated that not enough effort was put into the question to make it understandable. See, if you were to read the initial text of the question as if you were in our seat you'd realize that a lot more information was necessary. Just work harder on your next question. Happy coding!